# Page keeps freezing briefly when componentDidUpdate() is invoked

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently running into an issue when my REACT component uses `componentDidUpdate()` method. In this method the code updates and re-draws DataTables.net table. The freeze is about 7-10 seconds so I know its not during my API call as that takes about 25-30 seconds.

As a point of reference, in the `componentDidUpdate()` method I'm logging when the table is about to update. Once it logs to console the page freezes.

I've tried many different solutions which brought me to `componentDidUpdate()` method. I've even cleared this method of all code other than clearing and redrawing the table.

The objective of this program is to continuously poll and update the table

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
const $ = require('jquery');
$.DataTable = require('datatables.net');



function UpdateRibs() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(axios.post('/index', {'getRibs': 'getRibs'}));
    }, 35000);
  });
}


export class RibTable extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      ribs: ''
    };
    this.ribTable=React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
   this.getRibs()
  }

  async getRibs(){
    let response = await UpdateRibs()
    this.setState({ribs: response.data.data})
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.poll);
    $(this.ribTable.current).DataTable().destroy();
  }
  
  componentDidUpdate(prevState) {
    console.log('Updated')
    if (prevState.ribs !== this.state.ribs && this.ribTable !== undefined) {

        if ( $(this.ribTable.current).DataTable().data().any() ) {
          $(this.ribTable.current).DataTable().clear();
        }
        
        for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(this.state.ribs)){
          for (let item of value){
            $(this.ribTable.current).DataTable().row.add([
              item.name,
              item.address_family,
              item.dest_prefix,
              item.metric,
              item.route_preference,
              item.next_hop,
              item.outgoing_interface,
              item.active,
              item.source_protocol
            ]).draw(false).nodes()
            .to$().addClass('text-center')
          }
        }
        $(this.ribTable.current).fadeIn("slow");
        this.getRibs()
      }
  };

  render (){

    if (this.state.ribs == ''){

      return (
        
        <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body background blinking">
        <h3 class="card-header h3 background">Loading RIB Table<span class="h3 blinking">......</span></h3>
          <div class="loader"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

      );
    }
    else {
      return (
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header border-0">
                    <div class="row align-items-center">
                        <div class="col ">
                            <h4 class="mb-0">Rib Entries<span class="status" ref={this.status}>Idle
                              </span>
                              </h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <span class="counter pull-right"></span>
                    <br/>
                    <table class="display compact fadeTables" ref={this.ribTable}>
                        <thead class="thead-light" id='thead'>
                            <tr id='headr'>
                              <th class="text-center" scope="col">Name</th>
                              <th class="text-center" scope="col">Address-Family</th>
                              <th class="text-center" scope="col">Destination</th>
                              <th class="text-center" scope="col">Prefrence</th>
                              <th class="text-center" scope="col">Metric</th>
                              <th class="text-center" scope="col">Nex-Hop</th>
                              <th class="text-center" scope="col">Out Interface</th>
                              <th class="text-center" scope="col">Is Active</th>
                              <th class="text-center" scope="col">Source Protocol</th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                    </table>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>

      );
    };
  };
};
```

I updated the code and removed the ribs from this.state({}). So now the page only renders once and the table is updated without page render. I'm still experiencing the same issues and I believe it have to do with the table draw. In the updateTable() method I'm logging before and after the draw, this is where the 7-10 occurs.

```
function UpdateRibs() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(axios.post('/index', {'getRibs': 'getRibs'}));
    }, 5000);
  });
}

export class RibTable extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {renderPage: false};
    this.ribTable=React.createRef();
    this.ribs = ''
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getRibs()
  }

  async getRibs(){
    const res = await UpdateRibs()
    this.ribs = res.data.data
    console.log(this.res)

    if (this.state.renderPage === false){
      this.setState({renderPage: true})
    }
    
    this.updateTable()
    this.getRibs()
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.poll);
    $(this.ribTable.current).DataTable().destroy();
  }
  
  componentDidUpdate(prevState){
    if (prevState.renderPage != this.state.renderPage){
      $(this.ribTable.current).fadeIn("slow");
      console.log('Rendering')
    }
  }

  async updateTable(){

    console.log('Updating')
    
    if ( $(this.ribTable.current).DataTable().data().any() ) {
     $(this.ribTable.current).DataTable().destroy();
    }
    
    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(this.ribs)){
      for (let item of value){
        $(this.ribTable.current).DataTable().row.add([
          item.name,
          item.address_family,
          item.dest_prefix,
          item.metric,
          item.route_preference,
          item.next_hop,
          item.outgoing_interface,
          item.active,
          item.source_protocol
        ]).draw().nodes()
        .to$().addClass('text-center')
      }
    }
    console.log('Updated')

  }

  render (){

    if (this.state.renderPage === false){

      return (
        
        <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body background blinking">
        <h3 class="card-header h3 background">Loading RIB Table<span class="h3 blinking">......</span></h3>
          <div class="loader"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

      );
    }
    else {
      return (
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header border-0">
                    <div class="row align-items-center">
                        <div class="col ">
                            <h4 class="mb-0">Rib Entries<span class="status" ref={this.status}>Idle
                              </span>
                              </h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <span class="counter pull-right"></span>
                    <br/>
                    <table class="display compact fadeTables" ref={this.ribTable}>
                        <thead class="thead-light" id='thead'>
                            <tr id='headr'>
                              <th class="text-center" scope="col">Name</th>
                              <th class="text-center" scope="col">Address-Family</th>
                              <th class="text-center" scope="col">Destination</th>
                              <th class="text-center" scope="col">Prefrence</th>
                              <th class="text-center" scope="col">Metric</th>
                              <th class="text-center" scope="col">Nex-Hop</th>
                              <th class="text-center" scope="col">Out Interface</th>
                              <th class="text-center" scope="col">Is Active</th>
                              <th class="text-center" scope="col">Source Protocol</th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                    </table>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>

      );
    };
  };
};
```

Comment: try remove things inside `getRibs()` and see if it's still the case. If it isn't, then most likely you have a cycle of keeping calling `getRibs()`. For instance, if you change something, it'll try to render, but inside render, you are changing something again.

Comment: Unfortunately if I remove setSate() then the page will remain in the loading state. I failed to mention before this the goal of the program is to poll the device via API every 25 seconds. With that said this table will be constantly updating. I do have some program in flask/python. This uses AJAX calls, obviously not REACT. https://github.com/cober2019/IETF-RIB-Status

Comment: You did mention "if you change something, it'll try to render, but inside render, you are changing something again." So if i follow, if the this.state{rib} changes it will re render but im changing the table after the re render?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in fact drawing the table. What I did was build two methods, one to build the table and one to update. The first block of code is the update pushes the data into a new array and then I added in bulk to the table

```
updateTable(){

    let entries = []
  
    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(this.ribs)){
      for (let item of value){
        entries.push([ item.name,
         item.address_family,
         item.dest_prefix,
         item.metric,
         item.route_preference,
         item.next_hop,
         item.outgoing_interface,
         item.active,
         item.source_protocol])
      }
    }

    if ( $(this.ribTable.current).DataTable().data().any() ) {
      $(this.ribTable.current).DataTable().destroy();
    }
    $(this.ribTable.current).DataTable({data: entries})
    
  }

  buildTable(){

    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(this.ribs)){
      for (let item of value){
        $(this.ribTable.current).DataTable().row.add([
          item.name,
          item.address_family,
          item.dest_prefix,
          item.metric,
          item.route_preference,
          item.next_hop,
          item.outgoing_interface,
          item.active,
          item.source_protocol
        ]).draw().nodes()
        .to$().addClass('text-center')
      }
    }
  }
```

Full Code:

```
function UpdateRibs() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(axios.post('/index', {'getRibs': 'getRibs'}));
    }, 5000);
  });
}


export class RibTable extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {renderPage: false};
    this.ribTable=React.createRef();
    this.ribs = ''
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getRibs()
  }

  async getRibs(){
    const res = await UpdateRibs()
    this.ribs = res.data.data

    if (this.state.renderPage === false){
      this.setState({renderPage: true})
    }
  }

  async getUpdatedRibs(){
    const res = await UpdateRibs()
    this.ribs = res.data.data
    this.updateTable()
    this.getUpdatedRibs()
  }


  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.poll);
    $(this.ribTable.current).DataTable().destroy();
  }
  
  componentDidUpdate(prevState){
    if (prevState.renderPage != this.state.renderPage){
      console.log('Rendering')
      this.buildTable()
      $(this.ribTable.current).fadeIn("slow");
      this.getUpdatedRibs()
    }
  }

  updateTable(){

    let entries = []
  
    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(this.ribs)){
      for (let item of value){
        entries.push([ item.name,
         item.address_family,
         item.dest_prefix,
         item.metric,
         item.route_preference,
         item.next_hop,
         item.outgoing_interface,
         item.active,
         item.source_protocol])
      }
    }

    if ( $(this.ribTable.current).DataTable().data().any() ) {
      $(this.ribTable.current).DataTable().destroy();
    }
    $(this.ribTable.current).DataTable({data: entries})
    
  }

  buildTable(){

    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(this.ribs)){
      for (let item of value){
        $(this.ribTable.current).DataTable().row.add([
          item.name,
          item.address_family,
          item.dest_prefix,
          item.metric,
          item.route_preference,
          item.next_hop,
          item.outgoing_interface,
          item.active,
          item.source_protocol
        ]).draw().nodes()
        .to$().addClass('text-center')
      }
    }
  }

  render (){

    if (this.state.renderPage === false && this.ribs == ''){

      return (
        
        <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body background blinking">
        <h3 class="card-header h3 background">Loading RIB Table<span class="h3 blinking">......</span></h3>
          <div class="loader"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

      );
    }
    else {
      return (
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header border-0">
                    <div class="row align-items-center">
                        <div class="col ">
                            <h4 class="mb-0">Rib Entries<span class="status" ref={this.status}>Idle
                              </span>
                              </h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <span class="counter pull-right"></span>
                    <br/>
                    <table class="display compact fadeTables" ref={this.ribTable}>
                        <thead class="thead-light" id='thead'>
                            <tr id='headr'>
                              <th class="text-center" scope="col">Name</th>
                              <th class="text-center" scope="col">Address-Family</th>
                              <th class="text-center" scope="col">Destination</th>
                              <th class="text-center" scope="col">Prefrence</th>
                              <th class="text-center" scope="col">Metric</th>
                              <th class="text-center" scope="col">Nex-Hop</th>
                              <th class="text-center" scope="col">Out Interface</th>
                              <th class="text-center" scope="col">Is Active</th>
                              <th class="text-center" scope="col">Source Protocol</th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                    </table>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>

      );
    };
  };
};
```